# assigning to rvalue javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

```
    let newAllFields = allFields.map((f) => {
        (Number(id) === Number(f.id)) && f.hidden = true; 
        return f;
    });
```

Does anyone know why the above is giving a error? I'm getting

```
     Module build failed: SyntaxError:Field.js: 
     Assigning to rvalue (104:12)
```

I'm using react and babel with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Could you provide your snippet without the comment?

I can assume you want to filter  `allFields` array based on some properties of the elements.
In this case you probably want to use `filter()`, not `map()`, like this:

```
let newAllFields = allFields.filter((f) => {
  return Number(id) === Number(f.id) && f.hidden;
});
```

Comment: no, I need the full array back with just the change for the f.hidden property where the ids match. the code i posted is a shortcut for 

`(f) => {
  if (f.id === id) {
     f.hidden = true
  }
}`

Comment: [So that seems to be working](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20allFields%20%3D%20%5B%7Bid%3A%201%2C%20hidden%3A%20false%7D%2C%20%7Bid%3A2%2C%20hidden%3Afalse%7D%5D%3B%0Alet%20id%20%3D%201%3B%0Alet%20newAllFields%20%3D%20allFields.map((f)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(Number(id)%20%3D%3D%3D%20Number(f.id))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20f.hidden%20%3D%20true%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20console.log(newAllFields)%3B) Please provide your webpack config.

Comment: but it fails when you do it like i have in the original example [link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20allFields%20%3D%20[{id%3A%201%2C%20hidden%3A%20false}%2C%20{id%3A2%2C%20hidden%3Afalse}]%3B%0Alet%20id%20%3D%201%3B%0Alet%20newAllFields%20%3D%20allFields.map%28%28f%29%20%3D%3E%20{%0A%20%20%20%20%28Number%28id%29%20%3D%3D%3D%20Number%28f.id%29%29%20%26%26%20f.hidden%20%3D%20true%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0A%20%20}%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28newAllFields%29%3B)

Comment: When I ran it in the browser, it gave me a left-hand assignment error, when i wrapped the part after the &&, it worked no problem.

Comment: its not valid if statement, but in javascript if you write Boolean && function() and it will run depending on whether the Boolean is true or false. so it behaves like a valid if statement.

Comment: Yes, so wrap it in braces like `(Number(id) === Number(f.id)) && (f.hidden = true);` and it will work. It seems to be trying to assign a value to the logical and statement.